# How to color fill cells between range of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to develop an Excel spreadsheet to manage staff holidays. The idea is that there is a "Calendar" spreadsheet showing which holidays everyone takes.  Here is the screenshot:

[image: spreadsheet]

I use conditional formatting to fill the cells. Row 3 is formatted as date, showing only the day.  I compare the first holiday day (column B) and the last (column C) with the corresponding cell of the employee row.  If it falls within that date range, I fill it with green.

The problem with my current setup is that the holiday periods taken by the same employee are shown in different rows (see rows 4 and 6). I would like to show all the holidays on the same row for a given employee.

How can I achieve this? I guess I need some VBA, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: This is very confusing. It would be clearer to show another sheet of what you want rather than trying to say it in so many words. It's hard to ask a person to study your explanation at any length of time.

Comment: What is the formula for the column D cells?

Comment: You posted the worksheet you have screenshot, please fill another worksheet manually as you expect it to be and post one more screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need separate view with employee calendar from employee holiday list.
There is many possible ways to resolve this problem.